# Disk Recovery Software and Digital Rights Management

Tags: windows-media-player, deep-freeze

We are running Windows 7 - 64-bit with Windows Media Player 12 and Overdrive Media Console.  All of our PCs are "frozen" with DeepFreeze which is similar to CleanSlate or any other rollback/disk recovery applications upon reboot.

On public PCs, this is not an issue BUT our staff PCs are frozen too with a thawed area for ebook downloads and other work-related files.  Here is our dilemma: staff download an eBook with full DRM attached.  The book plays but the next day, the book remains but not the licensing as it is hidden somewhere on the C: drive and cannot be re-routed to the "thawed" storage area we have the books in.

In earlier version so Windows Media Player, you could change the target location of the DRM licences to follow wherever you stored the books.  WMP12 does not allow this.  The registry entry for this is in binary from what I can tell, hence having to be a software engineer to address such a tweak.  You also can't downgrade to an earlier version of WMP to get the target function back.

If anyone has any input, that would be great.

An addendum:

DeepFreeze Igloo is a migration tool that allows one to exclude by redirection folders/profiles/registry keys... However, seems DRM on Win7 64-bit is a bit more convoluted than we had thought.

Comment: I migrated this over as I think it will get a better answer here.

Comment: What does the file system layout look like exactly? Can you change the base system configuration, e.g. to include NTFS reparse points/links so that the DRM files actually reside on a different drive/folder while still appearing to reside in the original location?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, We've tried to do that with DeepFreeze Igloo (a re-direct tool that "should" have done the trick)... No luck as we can't trace the licensing to the DRM folder. It should appear but doesn't. WMP10 would allow DRM files to have a target path. Not so with WMP11/12 so now it's a totally different game.

Comment: An addendum: DeepFreeze Igloo is a migration tool that allows one to exclude by redirection folders/profiles/registry keys... However, seems DRM on Win7 64-bit is a bit more convoluted than we had thought.

Comment: Hi Lisa! Head over to [libraries.SE] and register your account via an OpenID. Then, use the same OpenID and register your Super User account. Once you've done that, you should have regained control over your question and will be able to edit it!

Comment: The registry entry you're referring to, is this `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\DRM\DataPath`? You can still double-click **DataPath** to see the location in the right column (the default location is **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\DRM**). You should be able to redirect that location with something like an NTFS junction.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but here is some documentation I found.

- Close WMP12
- Browse to %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\DRM and rename the folder to DRMbackup
- Open Internet Explorer as administrator (right click -> Run as Administrator)
  browse to http://drmlicense.one.microsoft.com/Indivsite/en/indivit.asp and click upgrade.
- Use data igloo to redirect the DRM folder -> thawspace.
- Authenticate the DRM'd files, reboot, and see if the authorization stays.